# 'Run as Spring Boot App' on STS but "webpage is not available" in the browser

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Like the title said, I right click on the spring boot project and Run as Spring Boot App. This is what I saw in the Console window of STS:

```
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.3.2.RELEASE)

2016-01-30 21:06:29.124  INFO 6584 --- [           main] l.IssueManagerApplication                : Starting IssueManagerApplication on LVN with PID 6584 (E:\_WORKSPACE\SPRING_BOOT\issue-manager\target\classes started by Le in E:\_WORKSPACE\SPRING_BOOT\issue-manager)
2016-01-30 21:06:29.130  INFO 6584 --- [           main] l.IssueManagerApplication                : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2016-01-30 21:06:29.249  INFO 6584 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@12d575ec: startup date [Sat Jan 30 21:06:29 EET 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-01-30 21:06:31.208  INFO 6584 --- [           main] f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
2016-01-30 21:06:32.032  INFO 6584 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2016-01-30 21:06:32.077  INFO 6584 --- [           main] l.IssueManagerApplication                : Started IssueManagerApplication in 4.163 seconds (JVM running for 6.548)
2016-01-30 21:06:32.078  INFO 6584 --- [       Thread-2] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@12d575ec: startup date [Sat Jan 30 21:06:29 EET 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-01-30 21:06:32.084  INFO 6584 --- [       Thread-2] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
```

And when I open localhost:8080, it just displayed a grey page saying "This webpage is not available". Apparently the server does not start at all or it started but then stopped right after that.

I already tried run `mvn spring-boot:run`, it also log out information as above plus `BUILD SUCCESS` and stops even without me `Ctrl + C`. So I dont know how to run my "hello world" spring-boot application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue by adding this in my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Thanks to this post:
[Why my Spring Boot App always shutdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22380119/why-my-spring-boot-app-always-shutdown)