# Camel EventNotifierSupport is not triggered with camel-spring-boot

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel

Found that Camel EventNotifierSupport is not triggered with camel-spring-boot. 
When working without camel-spring-boot, I am able to see this log. Should I use another lifecycle supporting class instead? Thanks in advance

```
2016-02-12 11:05:59,191 | main | INFO | com.ch.integration.camel.notifier.CamelEventNotifier | Started CamelContext: camel
2016-02-12 11:06:12,709 | Thread-0 | INFO | com.ch.integration.camel.notifier.CamelEventNotifier | Stopped CamelContext: camel
```

Comment: Provide more detail how you setup your application, maybe put a simple example on github somewhere etc.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your application is stopping soon after it starts, which means the app is not a webapp, since there is no embedded servlet container it is stopping. There are two ways to keep it running

1. Using Main class from Camel as mentioned in http://camel.apache.org/running-camel-standalone-and-have-it-keep-running.html
2. Adding spring-boot-starter-web dependency [Why does my Spring Boot App always shutdown immediately after starting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22380119/why-does-my-spring-boot-app-always-shutdown-immediately-after-starting)

Hope it helps, if the above assumption is not correct please provide some more console output, of DEBUG level.