# Spring Boot App Terminating at Startup

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am  trying out a simple spring boot application it always shuts down automatically

```
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.4.1.RELEASE)
2016-10-23 13:05:21.681  INFO 16532 --- [           main] com.example.RestBootApplication          : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2016-10-23 13:05:21.766  INFO 16532 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@6e20b53a: startup date [Sun Oct 23 13:05:21 EDT 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-10-23 13:05:23.682  INFO 16532 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2016-10-23 13:05:23.704  INFO 16532 --- [           main] com.example.RestBootApplication          : Started RestBootApplication in 2.632 seconds (JVM running for 5.168)
2016-10-23 13:05:23.705  INFO 16532 --- [       Thread-2] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@6e20b53a: startup date [Sun Oct 23 13:05:21 EDT 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-10-23 13:05:23.708  INFO 16532 --- [       Thread-2] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>rest-boot</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Main Class

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class RestBootApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(RestBootApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Controller

```
@Controller
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    String helloWorld(){
        return "helloWorld";
    }

}
```

Trying to run in spring tool suite.  it always stops after starting. I even added "spring-boot-starter-web" after looking at some stackoverflow  questions, but still facing the issue.

Please can you someone point out the issue.

Comment: try to remove this dependency < -spring-boot-starter- > from your pom

Comment: Have you refreshed your Eclipse buildpath etc. after adding `spring-boot-starter-web`? If not, then maybe your app is still running without it, which means after it is started, no other threads (like webserver) run, and thus the application context is immediately shutdown.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring boot application shutdown immediate after starting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39363570/spring-boot-application-shutdown-immediate-after-starting)

Answer (score 32):

In my case just adding following to pom file

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: `<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
` 
The spring-boot-starter-web dependency is starter for building web apps, including RESTful applications, using Spring MVC. It uses Tomcat web server as the default embedded container by including spring-boot-starter-tomcat, but you can use spring-boot-starter-jetty or spring-boot-starter-undertow instead which are starter for using Jetty and Undertow as the embedded servlet container.

Answer (score 17):

This was happening to me and it turned out to be a corrupted maven apache repository.

To fix it I removed the apache repo - on my Mac it was located at /Users/myname/.m2/repository/org/apache.

On a pc it should be c:\users\myname.m2\repository\org\apache.

I then ran Maven - Update Project and then I ran my class and it was fixed.

Comment: I was stuck with this problem and with many a stackoverflow question about this exact problem, and nobody had pointed out this stuff before. I guess this is why we don't like multiple questions about the same thing.

Comment: Thanks.It solved for me. But I was wondering how did you find the problem/solution?

Comment: I had triple checked the configuration so I knew everything was setup properly but it still wasn't working. So I figured something must have been corrupted when Maven was doing it's work so I removed the repo it and let Maven try again - et Viola!

Answer (score 8):

**Check what exit code you are getting.**

If you get **"Process finished with exit code 1"** means an exception is being thrown. Thus you can put a try catch block around your `SpringApplication.run()` statement and print out the stack trace.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    }
}
```

Example talen from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59017774/9531109

Answer (score 2):

**Solution to your Question**

1. I reviewed your POM.xml, it looks fine and doesn't require any changes to it.
2. `spring-boot-starter-web` is an opinionated dependency, it automatically pulls your other dependencies. Please check whether it has pulled your embedded Tomcat in your Maven Dependencies as shown below.

[image: Dep]

3. Go to application.properties file or application.yml to change the server port `server.port=9081`and run the maven goal as `mvn clean install spring-boot:run -e` 
    
    
   **If these options doesn't workout please try this approach [posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39245732/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-springframework-core-env-configurableenviron/39246493#39246493) by me.**

Answer (score 2):

First of all check if the port 8080 is available or is being used by some other process.

If this port is not available, try adding `server.port=someAvailablePortNumber` in the `application.properties` file located in "resources" folder.

I was also facing same problem. Tried a lot of changes suggested in pom.xml file and also tried multiple suggestion related to maven (e.g: deleting folder, updating project etc) but nothing worked for me. In my case the port 8080 wasn't available so application wasn't able to start tomcat using default port(i.e.: 8080) causing it to shutdown immediately.

Changing the port number helped to start tomcat and it started working. Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 2):

For me the embed tomcat was corrupted. I have done a mvn build and found below line as a WARNING.

[WARNING] error reading /home/syam/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/8.5.23/tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar; invalid LOC header (bad signature)

So deleted the tomcat embed directory and did a maven clean, things started working.

Answer (score 2):

If you have created the project using start.spring.io you might have missed to add 'Spring Web' dependency.

alternate we can add below code to pom.xml

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Mr. @Binod Singh .I included another spring web dependency instead of spring boot one....Thats why i was facing this issue and your comment helped me.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to remove this dependency

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

You may also try to add this tomcat dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: `spring-boot-starter-web` includes `spring-boot-starter`, so while it's not necessary to declare it separately, it doesn't harm and doesn't cause the problems.

Comment: Do you see this tomcat-embed-core jar  file in your maven dependncies folder ? or check the mvn log when you execute package phase ,and make sure that the tomcat-embed-core jar is assigned into you app jar.  if you do then your jar might be corrupted. Reload it

Comment: i deleted the application and switch to spring boot version <version>1.3.8.RELEASE</version> and the application was running. When i switch to 1.4.1 it didn't work

Comment: Same here, version 1.5.2.RELEASE stops immediately, 1.3.8.RELEASE works

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and there is how I resolved it :

- I deleted maven's local repository
- run again maven install
- run the app as spring boot app

====> Hallelujah, and it worked just by magic !

Comment: +1 I had the same problem on my Eclipse 2018-09 on Mac OS X. I tried installing lots of eclipse plugins. Doing a maven repository cleanup did the trick. And I don't know why it not works as well.

Answer (score 0):

I just took your code and started a Spring-Boot application from scratch. On my machine, your code starts up as expected when I run

```
mvn spring-boot:run
```

To make sure, we have the very same code, I uploaded my solution to Github, see https://github.com/michaellihs/stackoverflow-40205600

Just an idea why it doesn't work for you: do have another Tomcat instance running that is listening on port 8080 - this will stop your application immediately (but normally shows a different log / error message).

Answer (score 0):

In my case as well , I had to clear the complete .m2 directory and run clean install to make it to work. Not sure what is conflicting.

Answer (score 0):

i changed the port from 8080 to 8083 in application.properties which is under resources folder. server.port=8083 and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this for posterity.

For these kind of issues it is very advantageous to run `mvn help:effective-pom` and look at the versions that have been picked up. It is common to have a parent module that is overriding a module/version that spring-boot is expecting to be available.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and there is how I resolved it :
I changed version in `pom.xml` from `1.4.2.RELEASE` to `1.4.1.RELEASE`

Answer (score 0):

This property `spring.main.web-application-type= none` from the application properties file was causing the application to shut down as soon as started. Removing this would do the job.

Answer (score -1):

I deleted the maven dependencies folder and it worked for me

Comment: Better you add more details

Comment: I think he means that he deleted the maven repo and let maven re-download all the dependencies again.