# Migrating from Spring Boot 2.2.6 to 2.7.3

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea

I am working on migrating an enterprise web page from spring boot 2.2.6 to 2.7.3.
I am working in IntelliJ and Maven.
The project is successfully built by Maven but does not run.
The only error log is "Process finished with exit code 1". The other log messages are exactly the same as when 2.2.6.
I can't tell where the problem is.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Process finished with exit code 1 Spring Boot Intellij](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46428611/process-finished-with-exit-code-1-spring-boot-intellij)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone who have viewed this question.
It was not a simple, single question at all.
It was kind of a synthesized and complex problem.
First, spring-cloud version was the main problem. Spring Boot 2.7.3 does not support Spring Cloud Hoxton.SR11 which I have been using for Spring Boot 2.2.6.Release.
(Actually those who are migrating from Spring Boot 2.2-5.x to Spring Boot 2.2.x, choose Spring Boot 2.7.0 and Spring Cloud 2021.3. According to my experience, this combination is stable.)
Second, there were many trivial matters like

```yaml
spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding = true
spring.main.allow-circular-references = true
```

(There are still more tricky parts when migrating my own project.)
I hope to listen from those who have richer experience.
Thanks again.