# Spring Boot App shutdown immediately under spring-boot-starter-parent version 2.0.1.RELEASE

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I was studying JavaBrain's spring boot video and I ran into the same error as the link below.

[Why does my Spring Boot App always shutdown immediately after starting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22380119/why-does-my-spring-boot-app-always-shutdown-immediately-after-starting)

I have specified the dependency of spring-boot-starter-web, but still got the error. My pom.xml looks like this. The thing is when I change the version of spring-boot-starter-parent to 1.4.2.RELEASE everything works fine(I can access the localhost:8080). I wonder why this is happening and what can I do to make version 2.0.1.RELEASE to work.

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
  </parent>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

The code looks like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class CourseApiApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CourseApiApp.class, args);

    }

}
```

The output:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.0.1.RELEASE)

2018-04-16 21:42:07.576  INFO 8976 --- [           main] org.kouchibin.web.CourseApiApp           : Starting CourseApiApp on SAI with PID 8976 (C:\Users\86660\Documents\workspace-sts\course-api\target\classes started by kcb in C:\Users\86660\Documents\workspace-sts\course-api)
2018-04-16 21:42:07.583  INFO 8976 --- [           main] org.kouchibin.web.CourseApiApp           : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-04-16 21:42:07.670  INFO 8976 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@4c40b76e: startup date [Mon Apr 16 21:42:07 CST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-04-16 21:42:08.971  INFO 8976 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2018-04-16 21:42:08.990  INFO 8976 --- [           main] org.kouchibin.web.CourseApiApp           : Started CourseApiApp in 1.976 seconds (JVM running for 2.624)
2018-04-16 21:42:08.997  INFO 8976 --- [       Thread-2] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@4c40b76e: startup date [Mon Apr 16 21:42:07 CST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-04-16 21:42:09.000  INFO 8976 --- [       Thread-2] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
```

Comment: can you please post if with exception stack trace

Comment: there is just a misconfiguration or the web dependency is not loaded correctly. Just create a new project from [https://start.spring.io/](https://start.spring.io/). This will work 100%

Comment: @ElarbiMohamedAymen Sure. I have edited the original post.

Comment: @Patrick Nope. Not working either. I use STS to import the downloaded project. Same output. Can't figure out where I did wrong.

Comment: do you build the project and be sure that maven downloads all dependencies. Check again if you have the web inside your pom

Comment: Set the root logger to log DEBUG so that more logs can be displayed.

Comment: Problem solved. Check my answer to find out more. This is my first post in StackOverflow. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 1):

I already solved the problem. When I used `mvn compile` manually, instead of clicking the RUN button in eclipse, more details showed up, where some of the dependencies cannot be resolved. So I checked those dependencies in the local repository. The problem is that some dependencies are not downloaded completely(with a ".inprogress" suffix). So the way to solve this is to delete all those broken dependencies and recompile the application, which will download the dependencies again. I guess this problem is most probably occurs in China, where the connection to the maven repository is not stable because of the Great Firewall. And why 1.4.2.RELEASE worked is simply because all the dependencies are downloaded successfully by chance.