# Accessing the deployed service using Helm chart in Kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

Currently, I am trying to deploy my microservice end point Docker image on a Kubernetes cluster by creating the Helm chart. For this, I created the chart and changed the parameters in values.yaml and deployment.yaml for port change. And also I want to access from my Angular front end. So I added service type= NodePort. And when I described the service, it gave me the port `30983` to access.

And I accessed like http://node-ip:30983/endpoint

But I am only getting the site can't be reached the message. Let me add the details of what I did here:

My values.yaml file containing the following to mention the service type:

[image]

And my templates/service.yaml file containing like the following:

[image]

And my templates/deployment.yaml file containing the following:

[image]

And I tried to access like the following:

http://192.168.16.177:30983/

And only getting site can't be reached.

NB: when I tried to describe the service, then I am getting the following:

[image]

The output of **kubectl get pod --show-labels** like the following image screenshot

[image]

**Updated**

And when we using `kubectl describe pod` command, getting like the following:

[image]

**Updated Error**

```
Readiness probe failed: HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 404
Liveness probe failed: HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 404
```

How can I access my endpoint from deployment?

Comment: please provide output of "kubectl get pod --show-labels" and "kubectl get svc"

Comment: @VasilyAngapov - Yes sir, updated in question. And thank you for your response.

Comment: your pod is Crashlooping. Your app is crashing for some reason. You need to read logs "kubectl logs -p POD_NAME" where POD_NAME is the name of your failing pod.

Comment: @VasilyAngapov - I updated my result sir. Can you please look on updated question ?

Comment: you didn't provide the logs of crashlooping pods. Without logs nobody can help you. Read my previous comment again pls.

Comment: @VasilyAngapov - there is no crashlooping. Everything is running. I updated the last screenshot with the result. Did you checked that ?

Comment: please make sure your pod in Running 1/1 state. On your screenshot it is not ready.

Comment: @VasilyAngapov - Yes sir. When I run today , it showing now the crashloop. I updated the latest result with log also what I am getting. And thank you for your response sir.

Comment: as you see from the logs, your app is shut down right after starting. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22380119/why-does-my-spring-boot-app-always-shutdown-immediately-after-starting for more hints

Comment: @MarkusDresch - Thank sir for your response. I checked the link that you shared. I already have pom.xml in my root folder for "spring-boot-starter-web".

Comment: Hi Jacob. Please [read this article](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) when you get a moment - all of those images ought to be text/code blocks, for reasons given in the article.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this for healthcheck probes:

```
livenessProbe:
  tcpSocket:
    port: 8085
readinessProbe:
  tcpSocket:
    port: 8085
```

Comment: Ok sir, I will try this change. Thank you for your response.

Comment: I updated the question when i tried the kubectl describe pod. Can you look on that please?

Comment: your liveness probe returns 404, that's why your pod is restarting. Liveness probe must only return HTTP response 200. Find a path where it returns 200 or use tcpSocket probe.

Comment: @Jacob I've updated my answer, can you try it and tell if it helps?

Answer (score 1):

try the following command `docker ps -a` and find the container associated with the pod. The container name should be pretty much same as the pod name with some prefix/suffix.

then look at the logs using `docker logs <container_id>`. Maybe that will give you clues to what it is restarting