# SpringBoot application shuts down when running using JAR, but works well when running from cmd or VSCode

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, jar

I am trying to run a SpringBoot application from a JAR file, which I have built using VSCode's Project Manager from Java.

The app runs smoothly when running from VSCode, or when running from the command line, using

```
mvn spring-boot:run
```

This is my Main Class file:

```
package com.jvc.interconnectingflights.app;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("com.jvc.interconnectingflights")
public class InterconnectingFlightsApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(InterconnectingFlightsApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

This is my pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.jvc</groupId>
    <artifactId>interconnecting-flights</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>interconnecting-flights</name>
    <description>SpringBoot app</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.22</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

This is the output I am getting when running from the JAR:

```
22:05:28.287 [main] INFO com.jvc.interconnectingflights.app.InterconnectingFlightsApplication - Started InterconnectingFlightsApplication in 3.102 seconds (process running for 3.46)
22:05:28.318 [SpringApplicationShutdownHook] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext - Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@78e94dcf, started on Tue Jan 31 22:05:25 CET 2023
```

I have tried all the answers from related posts, but still no luck. I would really appreciate any advice!

Tried answers from this post and related ones:

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22380119/why-does-my-spring-boot-app-always-shutdown-immediately-after-starting](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: Do you run your jar file like `$ java -jar target/app.war`?

Comment: @MaiGoL7 I run it like this 
` java -jar .\InterconnectingFlightsApplication.jar `
I am using Windows by the way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Created a new JAR using `mvn package`, which turned out to work. VSCode's Java Project Manager doesn't seem to build the JAR correctly

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the java version defined in your pom file match or lower than that installed in your computer for example if installed java 16 you need version 16 or lower in your dependence file. some IDE use the builtin java SDKs or JDK plugins.