# my spring boot app shuts down as soon as i open it

Tags: java, spring-boot, mariadb

im having the same issue a lot of people are having that the server exits as soon as i try to run it.

i tried following the advice from this stackoverflow but no luck:
[Why does my Spring Boot App always shutdown immediately after starting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22380119/why-does-my-spring-boot-app-always-shutdown-immediately-after-starting)

its literally a new server so not sure what the issue is.
i have a connection with a mariadb but i dont think that that is the issue.

this is my folder structure::

[image: folder_structure]

this is my entry point::

```
package com.worknow.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);

    }


}
```

this is my controller:

```
package com.worknow.demo.controllers;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/")
public class DynamicController {

    @PostMapping("{tableName}/{id}")
    public String postRequest(@PathVariable String tableName, @PathVariable String id, @RequestBody String requestBody) {
        return "Hello, POST request for table: " + tableName + " and id: " + id + "! You sent: " + requestBody;
    }

    @GetMapping("a")
    public String getRequest() {
        return "Hello, GET request!";
    }
}
```

this my dependecies::

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

this is the output i see on the terminal::

```
/Users/juan/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-21.0.1/Contents/Home/bin/java -javaagent:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar=50464:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.stdout.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.stderr.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /Users/juan/Desktop/dev/code/worknow/target/classes:/Users/juan/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter/3.2.4/spring-boot-starter-3.2.4.jar:/Users/juan/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/3.2.4/spring-boot-3.2.4.jar:/Users/juan/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/6.1.5/spring-context-6.1.5.jar:/Users/juan/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aop/6.1.5/spring-aop-6.1.5.jar:/Users/juan/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-expression/6.1.5/spring-expression-6.1.5.jar:/Users/juan/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/3.2.4/spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.2.4.jar:/Users/juan/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-logging/3.2.4/spring-boot-starter-logging-3.2.4.jar:/Users/juan/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.4.14/logback-classic-1.4.14.jar:/Users/juan/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-core/1.4.14/logback-core-1.4.14.jar:/Users/juan/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-to-slf4j/2.21.1/log4j-to-slf4j-2.21.1.jar:/Users/juan/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-api/2.21.1/log4j-api-2.21.1.jar:/Users/juan/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/2.0.12/jul-to-slf4j-2.0.12.jar:/Users/juan/.m2/repository/jakarta/annotation/jakarta.annotation-api/2.1.1/jakarta.annotation-api-2.1.1.jar:/Users/juan/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/6.1.5/spring-core-6.1.5.jar:/Users/juan/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-jcl/6.1.5/spring-jcl-6.1.5.jar:/Users/juan/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/2.2/snakeyaml-2.2.jar:/Users/juan/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-jdbc/3.2.4/spring-boot-starter-jdbc-3.2.4.jar:/Users/juan/.m2/repository/com/zaxxer/HikariCP/5.0.1/HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:/Users/juan/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/2.0.12/slf4j-api-2.0.12.jar:/Users/juan/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-jdbc/6.1.5/spring-jdbc-6.1.5.jar:/Users/juan/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-tx/6.1.5/spring-tx-6.1.5.jar:/Users/juan/.m2/repository/org/mariadb/jdbc/mariadb-java-client/3.3.3/mariadb-java-client-3.3.3.jar:/Users/juan/.m2/repository/com/github/waffle/waffle-jna/3.3.0/waffle-jna-3.3.0.jar:/Users/juan/.m2/repository/net/java/dev/jna/jna/5.13.0/jna-5.13.0.jar:/Users/juan/.m2/repository/net/java/dev/jna/jna-platform/5.13.0/jna-platform-5.13.0.jar:/Users/juan/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/2.0.12/jcl-over-slf4j-2.0.12.jar:/Users/juan/.m2/repository/com/github/ben-manes/caffeine/caffeine/3.1.8/caffeine-3.1.8.jar:/Users/juan/.m2/repository/com/google/errorprone/error_prone_annotations/2.21.1/error_prone_annotations-2.21.1.jar:/Users/juan/.m2/repository/org/checkerframework/checker-qual/3.32.0/checker-qual-3.32.0.jar:/Users/juan/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-web/6.1.3/spring-web-6.1.3.jar:/Users/juan/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/6.1.5/spring-beans-6.1.5.jar:/Users/juan/.m2/repository/io/micrometer/micrometer-observation/1.12.4/micrometer-observation-1.12.4.jar:/Users/juan/.m2/repository/io/micrometer/micrometer-commons/1.12.4/micrometer-commons-1.12.4.jar com.worknow.demo.DemoApplication

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.2.4)

2024-03-30T10:01:48.474-05:00  INFO 15474 --- [           main] com.worknow.demo.DemoApplication         : Starting DemoApplication using Java 21.0.1 with PID 15474 (/Users/juan/Desktop/dev/code/worknow/target/classes started by juan in /Users/juan/Desktop/dev/code/worknow)
2024-03-30T10:01:48.475-05:00  INFO 15474 --- [           main] com.worknow.demo.DemoApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2024-03-30T10:01:48.808-05:00  INFO 15474 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2024-03-30T10:01:48.879-05:00  INFO 15474 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection org.mariadb.jdbc.Connection@60d1b21f
2024-03-30T10:01:48.879-05:00  INFO 15474 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2024-03-30T10:01:48.937-05:00  INFO 15474 --- [           main] com.worknow.demo.DemoApplication         : Started DemoApplication in 0.671 seconds (process running for 0.883)
2024-03-30T10:01:48.939-05:00  INFO 15474 --- [ionShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2024-03-30T10:01:48.941-05:00  INFO 15474 --- [ionShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.

Process finished with exit code 0
```

these are my properties for my dev server::

```
server.port=8093

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/work_now_dev?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=12345678
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.main.web-application-type=none
```

i put the debug logs here::
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1OeilN98doT7FGsZJhghx38xt_tc0sN6HHrJeK8NR8YA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Do you have a reproducer, .e.g. a git repository?

Comment: Tomcat needs to be available at runtime also. Remove the line `<scope>compile</scope>` from the tomcat dependency

Comment: @devatherock thank you. i did what you said but no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything looks fine! I think you need to update your IntelliJ Idea IDE and restart it!

That will fix the issue I guess.

Comment: i tried that but no luck

Comment: Great! Keep working.

Comment: does anyone know why my question got blocked?
im not sure what i am doing wrong

Comment: You need to add the debugging details to it! A code to reproduce the same error!